# How do you initialize an object in `new` action, then update it in `create`?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller

### Objective

Initialize a new addition problem for users to solve when they visit `/task`. They input their answer, and the form submits back to `/task`. The `new` action should initialize the problem, since users cannot edit the problem, only provide an answer. The `create` action should update the table `addition_tasks` in the column `answer` with the user's submitted answer.

### Problem

As I currently have it, the task is created and saved successfully in the `new` action, but fails to update with the `create` action.

#### Model

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: addition_tasks
#
#  id            :integer         not null, primary key
#  first_addend  :integer
#  second_addend :integer
#  sum           :integer
#  answer        :integer
#  correct       :boolean
#  created_at    :datetime        not null
#  updated_at    :datetime        not null
#

class AdditionTask < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :answer

  belongs_to :user
end
```

#### Routes

```
  match 'task', to: 'addition_task#new'
  match 'task', to: 'addition_task#create'
```

#### Controller

```
class AdditionTaskController < ApplicationController

  respond_to :html, :js

  def new
    @task = AdditionTask.new
    @task = new_task(@task)
    @task.save
    session[:task_id] = @task.id
  end

  def create
    @task = AdditionTask.find(session[:task_id])
    @task.answer = params[:addition_task][:answer]
    respond_with :new
  end

  private

  def new_task(task)
    @task.first_addend = 1 + Random.rand(98)
    @task.second_addend = 1 + Random.rand(98)
    @task.sum = @task.first_addend + @task.second_addend
    @task
  end
end
```

#### View

```
%h1 Problem
:markdown
  Please answer the question below. You may press "Enter" from within the answer field, instead of clicking the button, in order to receive a new question.

#task-container
  .addend
    =@task.first_addend
  .operator
    +
  .addend
    =@task.second_addend
  .operator
    \=
  .answer
    =simple_form_for @task, url: task_path, defaults: {input_html: {class: 'span2'}}, html: { class: 'form-inline' } do |f|
      =f.input :answer, label: false
      =f.submit :submit, class: 'btn-primary btn-large pull-right', value: 'Answer'

%div
  =@task.sum
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Siwei's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9858593/402618) and [lee's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9858575/402618) both made excellent points.

Thanks to some folks in #rubyonrails, I moved the code from `create` to `update`. I also changed my routes, as Siwei suggested, and saved the object, as lee suggested. However, I used `@obj.save!` in order to get some helpful errors if something went wrong.

### New Routes

```
  resources :users
  resources :addition_tasks, path: 'task', only: [:new, :update]

  root to: 'site#home'
  match 'signup',  to: 'users#new'
  match 'signin',  to: 'sessions#new'
```

### New Controller

```
class AdditionTasksController < ApplicationController

  respond_to :html, :js

  def new
    @task = AdditionTask.new
    @task = new_task(@task)
    @task.save!
    session[:task_id] = @task.id
  end

  def update
    @task = AdditionTask.find(session[:task_id])
    @task.answer = params[:addition_task][:answer]
    @task.save!
    render action: :new
  end

  private

  def new_task(task)
    @task.first_addend = 1 + Random.rand(98)
    @task.second_addend = 1 + Random.rand(98)
    @task.sum = @task.first_addend + @task.second_addend
    @task
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to save your task:

```
def create
  logger.info("session's task_id: #{session[:task_id]}")

  @task = AdditionTask.find(session[:task_id])
  logger.info("@task.id: #{@task.id}")

  @task.answer = params[:addition_task][:answer]
  logger.info("@task.answer: #{@task.answer}")

  @task.save
  logger.info("@task: #{@task.inspect}")

  respond_with(@task)
end
```

Comment: The task is saved in `new`, it shouldn't need to be saved again in `create`. `@task.answer` should update the task object's `answer` attribute. In any case, I tried adding it, and it didn't fix my problem.

Comment: The task does need to be saved again, since `@task.answer = ` doesn't interact with the database until `save` is called.  I updated my code to add some logging, try running that and pasting the output of your `create` action from the development log.

Comment: Thanks, lee. I figured it out, with help from #rubyonrails. I needed to move everything from `create` to `update` since I was first saving the object in `new`.

Answer (score 2):

I think your routes.rb has problems:

```
match 'task', to: 'addition_task#new'   
match 'task', to: 'addition_task#create'
```

since Rails won't know in which case it should send the request to which action.

I suggest you use RESTful routes:

```
resources :addition_tasks
```

then it will generate  2 routes for you:

```
GET :new 
POST :create
```

for more details of the usages of RESTful route, please refer to rails official doc. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#paths-and-urls

Comment: I initially tried this with RESTful routes only on `create` and `new`, but it wasn't working then, either. I really think the issue is with the controller. 

Rails handles different request type to the same URL with native RESTful routes. I shouldn't have a problem defining my own. If the request is a `GET` request to `task`, it should go to `#new`, if `POST`, it should go to `#create`. I'll read over the docs again to see if I missed something.